# Capture AJAX responses like Firebug with the c# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, browser, firebug

I only want to capture the returned AJAX Response of a website.
I don't want to wait of the completed manipulated DOM Document. I want to capture the response like the Firebug console.

regards Chris

Comment: do you want something like http monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler Core](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/core/) maybe, that a bit overweight solution, but works nicely.